# Failed to parse time string, Magento 2

Tags: magento2, datetime

I am getting date value as:

```
 $lifetime = date('d/m/Y', $exptime);
```

and saving into custom table. It was working fine untill last working day, I didn't pushed any thing and now I am getting error

> Message: DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string
>   (15/12/2020) at position 0 (1): Unexpected character
>   {"exception":"[object] (Exception(code: 0)

Why it happened any clue ?